# How to get Red5 working?

Tags: package-management, tomcat, red5

I installed Red5 from the Ubuntu universe repository. After installation, I visited `http://localhost:5080`. The page looked like this:

[image]

As you can see, there's a broken image on the page. As well, none of the internal links on the page work (they give 404 errors). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I installed `red5` and can not confirm your problem. 2 packages got installed: `libred5-java` and `red5server`.

After install all I did was `http://localhost:5080` and it gets me the following page:

[image: im2]

The name of the image is biglogo5.png
All the links work and I get more on the page then you on your screenshot.

Reinstall and it should all Just Work tm.